# How to transform output of NN, while still being able to train?

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, backpropagation

I have a neural network which outputs `output`. I want to transform `output` before the loss and backpropogation happen.

Here is my general code:

```
with torch.set_grad_enabled(training):
                  outputs = net(x_batch[:, 0], x_batch[:, 1]) # the prediction of the NN
                  # My issue is here:
                  outputs = transform_torch(outputs)
                  loss = my_loss(outputs, y_batch)

                  if training:
                      scheduler.step()
                      loss.backward()
                      optimizer.step()
```

Following the advice in [How to transform output of neural network and still train?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70040998/how-to-transform-output-of-neural-network-and-still-train) , I have a transformation function which I put my output through:

```
def transform_torch(predictions):
    new_tensor = []
    for i in range(int(len(predictions))):
      arr = predictions[i]
      a = arr.clone().detach() 
      
      # My transformation, which results in a positive first element, and the other elements represent decrements of the first positive element.
     
      b = torch.negative(a)
      b[0] = abs(b[0])
      new_tensor.append(torch.cumsum(b, dim = 0))

      # new_tensor[i].requires_grad = True
    new_tensor = torch.stack(new_tensor, 0)    

    return new_tensor
```

Note: In addition to `clone().detach()`, I also tried the methods described in [Pytorch preferred way to copy a tensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55266154/pytorch-preferred-way-to-copy-a-tensor), to similar result.

My problem is that no training actually happens with this tensor that is tranformed.

If I try to modify the tensor in-place (e.g. directly modify `arr`), then Torch complains that I can't modify a tensor in-place with a gradient attached to it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Definitely don't call `detach`, that clears the gradient. What is the point of `b`? It's not used.

Comment: I fixed the ```b``` variable. The reason why I currently call ```detach``` is if I don't call detach, I can't edit the tensor without Pytorch complaining.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `detach` on your `predictions` stops gradient propagation to your model. Nothing you do after that can change your parameters.

How about modifying your code to avoid this:

```py
def transform_torch(predictions):
  b = torch.cat([predictions[:, :1, ...].abs(), -predictions[:, 1:, ...]], dim=1)
  new_tensor = torch.cumsum(b, dim=1)
  return new_tensor
```

---

A little test you can run, to verify that gradients do propagate through this transformation is:

```py
# start with some random tensor representing the input predictions
# make sure it requires_grad
pred = torch.rand((4, 5, 2, 3)).requires_grad_(True)
# transform it
tpred = transform_torch(pred)

# make up some "default" loss function and back-prop
tpred.mean().backward()

# check to see all gradients of the original prediction:
pred.grad
# as you can see, all gradients are non-zero
Out[]:
tensor([[[[ 0.0417,  0.0417,  0.0417],
          [ 0.0417,  0.0417,  0.0417]],

         [[-0.0333, -0.0333, -0.0333],
          [-0.0333, -0.0333, -0.0333]],

         [[-0.0250, -0.0250, -0.0250],
          [-0.0250, -0.0250, -0.0250]],

         [[-0.0167, -0.0167, -0.0167],
          [-0.0167, -0.0167, -0.0167]],

         [[-0.0083, -0.0083, -0.0083],
          [-0.0083, -0.0083, -0.0083]]],


        [[[ 0.0417,  0.0417,  0.0417],
          [ 0.0417,  0.0417,  0.0417]],

         [[-0.0333, -0.0333, -0.0333],
          [-0.0333, -0.0333, -0.0333]],

         [[-0.0250, -0.0250, -0.0250],
          [-0.0250, -0.0250, -0.0250]],

         [[-0.0167, -0.0167, -0.0167],
          [-0.0167, -0.0167, -0.0167]],

         [[-0.0083, -0.0083, -0.0083],
          [-0.0083, -0.0083, -0.0083]]],


        [[[ 0.0417,  0.0417,  0.0417],
          [ 0.0417,  0.0417,  0.0417]],

         [[-0.0333, -0.0333, -0.0333],
          [-0.0333, -0.0333, -0.0333]],

         [[-0.0250, -0.0250, -0.0250],
          [-0.0250, -0.0250, -0.0250]],

         [[-0.0167, -0.0167, -0.0167],
          [-0.0167, -0.0167, -0.0167]],

         [[-0.0083, -0.0083, -0.0083],
          [-0.0083, -0.0083, -0.0083]]],


        [[[ 0.0417,  0.0417,  0.0417],
          [ 0.0417,  0.0417,  0.0417]],

         [[-0.0333, -0.0333, -0.0333],
          [-0.0333, -0.0333, -0.0333]],

         [[-0.0250, -0.0250, -0.0250],
          [-0.0250, -0.0250, -0.0250]],

         [[-0.0167, -0.0167, -0.0167],
          [-0.0167, -0.0167, -0.0167]],

         [[-0.0083, -0.0083, -0.0083],
          [-0.0083, -0.0083, -0.0083]]]])
```

If you'll try this little test with your original code you'll either get an error that you are trying to propagate through tensors that do not `require_grad`, or you'll get no grads for the input `pred`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Shai. However, I notice that only the first value in the tensor will be trained. Any suggestions to this?

Comment: @GalenBlueTalon why only the first? which first, channel?

Answer (score -1):

How about extracting grad from the tensor with something like this

```
  grad = output.grad
```

and after the transformation assigning the same gradient to new tensor

Comment: You are actually proposing to **explicitly** implement the `backward` function of `transform_torch`. This is not always trivial and is very error-prone. But you can do that, see [this tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/examples_autograd/two_layer_net_custom_function.html) on implementing a custom function with its derivative.